# Nginx location block behave recursively

Tags: nginx

I have the following `location` block in nginx:

```
location /stats {
  allow 127.0.0.1;
  deny all;
}
```

If I try and view `/stats` from my home MacBook I get `403 Forbidden` as expected. However, if I view `/stats/index.php` I am able to view it. I was under the impression the `location /stats` would apply recursively (i.e. to all children).

How do I make this location block behave as expected?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You need to specify location 'beginning with':

```
location ^~ /stats {
  allow 127.0.0.1;
  deny all;
}
```

Comment: You were faster :)